# Android listview simple_list_item_checked

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that uses the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` layout.

I need the app to detect when the user checks an item in the listview and passes the state of the checkbox to a variable.

How is this done? Remember Im not using a custom layout for the listview. Im using the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to enable the `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` in your layout XML for the `listview` that you created.

Then set the `onItemClickListener` on your `listview` like :

```
@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    System.out.println("Clicked Position := "+position +" Value: "+sparseBooleanArray.get(position));
  }
```

Comment: Ok that has worked. I have also saved the state of the check to sharedpreferences but now I don't know how to set an item to checked pragmatically.

Comment: You can checked any item easily if you know the position of that item into the  listview. please use this code 

listview.setItemChecked(position, value); 
where position is the location of the item and the value can be only true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe helps you

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)v;
    textview.setChecked(!textview.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: I tried that but when I click the list item nothing appears to happen.